# Passing a JSON array while calling another feature file

Tags: json, karate

As Per https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features when we pass a JSON array as an argument to the call of another feature file, the feature is invoked for each item in the array.

Is there a way to avoid this? I want to consider the complete JSON array as my request for another feature file
Example:

```
[
 {
   "attr1" :"123",
   "attr2" :"456"
 },
 {
   "attr1" :"789",
   "attr2" :"101112"
 }
]
```

I'm currently passing this payload to another feature file as:

```
* call read('classpath:com/example/Test.feature') myReq
```

Now my Test.feature gets executed twice, once for each item in the JSON array. But my complete JSON array is to be passed as Request to Test.feature. How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it:

```
* def array = []
* def arg = { data: '#(array)' }
* call read('classpath:com/example/Test.feature') arg
```