# Passing a JSON array to another feature file

Tags: json, karate

I would like to pass the JSON array to the another feature file as an argument and I am using the below steps:
Below is the json array, I have to pass

```
[
  {
    "attr1": 14,
    "attr2": 1
  }
]
```

The Code I have written is:

```
      * def requestPayload = read('classpath:api/data/request/deliveryrank/sample.json')
      * def addProjects = call read('classpath:api/features/common/example.feature') requestPayload
```

I tried using the method explained in "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68986777/passing-a-json-array-while-calling-another-feature-file" but the request is send like

```
* def array = [{"attr1": 14,"attr2": 1}]
* def arg = { data: '#(array)' }
* call read('classpath:com/example/Test.feature') arg
```

Request in call:

```
{"data":[{"attr1":14,"attr2":1}]}
```

but it should go as it is [{"attr1": 14,"attr2": 1}]

Comment: I pass as this is incomplete and too complicated to understand.

Comment: It is now working, I was not referring to it properly. In Test.feature I am now referring it as arg.data to get the array directly. Thanks @PeterThomas.